# How correct handle http post request when server is not available?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7

How to handle correct http post response when server is not available?

Now I send request like:

```
    this.requestMethods.SendCurrentStep(this.formRegister.currentForm().index).subscribe(() => {
       // TODO
    });

// Code below is not executed father
```

Method is:

```
public SendCurrentStep(step: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post('https://localhost:9090/NotAvailableUrl', {
      'step' : step
    })
      .map(res => (<any>res)._body === '' ? {} : res)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your server is not available, that's up to `RXJS` to tell you.

```
this.requestMethods.SendCurrentStep(this.formRegister.currentForm().index)
.subscribe(
(sucessResponse) => 
  {
       // TODO your stuff with returned data
  },
(errorResponse) => 
  {
      // Here if the response is falsey -i.e: code = 500 / 404 ...
  }

);
```

You have nothing to implement in the front side of the app, you only have to ensure that the response code status are well sent from the backend, as well as responses. **Check [here](https://angular.io/guide/observables#error-handling) (*and the whole page*) for more information.**

**PS**: remove the `.catch(this.handleError);` and I think as well as the `.map(res => (<any>res)._body === '' ? {} : res)` because am not sure what that is meant to be there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to throw the error from your first subscribe, so the second subscribe receives it. Something like this...

```
public SendCurrentStep(step: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post('https://localhost:9090/NotAvailableUrl', {
      'step' : step
    })
      .map(res => (<any>res)._body === '' ? {} : res)
      .catch((error) =>
    {
       Observable.throw(this.handleError(e)))
    });
  }
```

Then you can catch it just the same way in your second subscribe

```
this.requestMethods.SendCurrentStep(this.formRegister.currentForm().index).subscribe(() => {
       // TODO
    }).catch((error) => {
   Console.log("There was a problem sending this request");
});
```

Is that what you meant? If you meant how can you tell that the server is down, as opposed to there being an internal server error, or an invalid request - you can't really. You could use the response code?